# react-mentions debounce input text

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, debouncing

I'm using react-mention to allow the user to @someone in a chat. The suggestions are loaded from the backend. After the user types "@", I want to hit the server only once after they have stopped typing. I tried using lodash debounce but I don't think I'm using it correctly because all it does is wait for some time and then call the server multiple times.

```
const fetchUsernames = debounce((query, callback) => {
    if (query.length > 2) {
      console.log("fetching usernames for query", query);
      axios
        .get(`users/query/${query}`)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.data)
            return response.data.map((u) => ({ id: u, display: u }));
          else return [];
        })
        .then(callback);
    }
  }, 1000);

return (
    <MentionsInput
      value={message}
      onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
    >
      <Mention
        trigger="@"
        data={fetchUsernames}
      />
    </MentionsInput>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix by move `fetchUsernames` to outside the component

**Update**: If you want to use `fetchUsernames` in component, use can using `useCallback` like this.

```
const fetchUsernames = useCallback(
    debounce((query, callback) => {
      ...
    }, 1000),
    []
  );
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! But is there any solution that keeps the fetchUsernames in the component so I can access loading state and display loading?

Comment: I updated solution if you want keep `fetchUsernames ` in the component